# the_post_thumbnail wordpress not displaying the picture

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi please assist on where i am going wrong. Trying to show the image on the post even after inserting the post_thumbnail in the functions.php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="list-image border-one">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( ''); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="list-info">
            <h2>Please Help Refugees</h2>
            <p><span>85%</span> Donated / <span>$7,291</span> To Go</p>
            <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Donate Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's going wrong? Are you getting an error message? What does the produced HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're passing an empty string in for the `$size` parameter. Use the following instead:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`
instead of `<?php the_post_thumbnail( ''); ?>`.

If it still doesnot display the picture. Reupload the picture.